# What is the difference between arguments and parameters in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I know that a parameter is a variable passed to a function and gives value to the argument in the function, but I'm having trouble understanding:

What is the main difference between "arguments" and "parameters" in javascript?

Comment: Different words for the same thing.

Comment: there's something called `arguments` also.

have a [look](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments).

Comment: Great answers guys! Thanks for taking me out the the doubt.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

The parameters are the *aliases* for the values that will be passed to the function. The arguments are the actual values.

```
var foo = function( a, b, c ) {}; // a, b, and c are the parameters

foo( 1, 2, 3 ); // 1, 2, and 3 are the arguments
```

Comment: If you called `foo` like `foo( x, y, z)`, are `x`, `y`, and `z` the arguments or are the *values* of `x`, `y`, and `z` the arguments? I don't know if the answer is important, I'm just curious.

Comment: @DanielKaplan The variables are the same as their values. Calling `foo(x, y, z)` is the same as `foo(1, 2, 3)` for instance.

Comment: Sorry, my question wasn't clear. I was asking about the appropriate terminology, specifically about the term "argument" in this context. When you call a function by passing in variables, are the *variable names* the "arguments" or the "variable values"?

Comment: @DanielKaplan The variable names are the arguments.

Answer (score 4):

When you define a function, the variables that represent the values that will be passed to it for processing are called parameters. For example, the following function definition has one parameter called $number:

```
function doubleIt($number) {
    return $number *= 2;
}
```

However, when you use a function, the value you pass to it is called an argument. So, in the following case, $price is passed as the argument to doubleIt():

```
$price = 50;
$inflated_price = doubleIt($price);  // 100
```

Comment: What do you mean by "the parameters are what are used inside the function"?

Answer (score 2):

parameters (if any) *define* the method signature. 
Arguments are values *passed* into a function.

But same difference I guess.

`void function(int param1, string param2) //defines the types the function must receive`.

`function(1, "Hello World")` 1 and "Hello World" are passed as arguments. The parameter receives (if you like) the argument.

It is explained well [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9kewt1b3%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: I thought those words meant the same thing, maybe you can clarify with an example?

Comment: @WesleyMurch Not really. Look at the link in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Parameters are properties of a *function*.

Arguments are properties of a *particular call* to a function.

In javascript, if you don't give a number of arguments equal to the number of parameters, the extra come across as `undefined`.

```
function f(a,b,c) // 3 parameters
f(1) // 1 argument given; inside the function f, a will be 1, and b and c will be undefined
```

Answer (score 1):

> #### [13 Function Definition](http://es5.github.com/#x13)
>
> Syntax
>
> ```
> FunctionDeclaration : 
>     function Identifier ( FormalParameterList (opt) ) { FunctionBody } 
> FunctionExpression : 
>     function Identifieropt ( FormalParameterList (opt) ) { FunctionBody } 
> FormalParameterList : 
>     Identifier 
>     FormalParameterList , Identifier 
> FunctionBody : 
>     SourceElements (opt)
> ```

Officially they are called parameters, but the actual arguments are given in the same called object. However, both words are interchangeable.

Answer (score -1):

so parameters works just like a place holder for your arguments
when you going to call the function to give it a value you will give the function a value and that value stored in the place of parameter1 and parameter2

```js
function add (parameter1 , parameter2 ) {
  return parameter1 + parameter2; 
}

add(10 (argument 1), 20 (argument2 ))
```