# Anonymous callback function throwing errors, making one to traverse the array like forEach

Tags: javascript, arrays, callback, functional-programming

```
function each(collec,function(){
    for(var key in collec){
      console.log(collec[key]);
    }
  }
);

------------------------------------------
Line 1: Expected an identifier and instead saw 'function' (a reserved word).
Line 1: Expected ')' to match '(' from line 1 and instead saw '('.
Line 1: 'function closure expressions' is only available in Mozilla JavaScript extensions (use moz option).
Line 1: Expected an identifier and instead saw ')'.
Line 6: Expected an identifier and instead saw ')'.
Line 6: Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression.
```

Comment: If you're trying to call a function called each, remove the `function` keyword from the beginning. That is only used when declaring new functions.

Comment: nope, i am declaring it! not calling it!

Comment: Okay, so the callback needs to be passed in when you call it, not when you declare it :)

Answer (score 1):

we pass **arguments** when calling a function but here

```
function each(collec,function(){
    for(var key in collec){
      console.log(collec[key]);
    }
  }
);
```

you are declaring a function so you need to specify **parameters** like the following

```
function each(collec , temp){
   .... fxn code
}
```

[What is the difference between arguments and parameters in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12874467/what-is-the-difference-between-arguments-and-parameters-in-javascript)

Comment: Thanks!
one more thing i have an array,
var array = [1,2,3,4,5];
i have a function print(), that prints just one element at a time, let us say every element of array in this context!(if called times the length of array)
NOW I WANT A FUNCTION LIKE,
each(arr,print)
that would console.log all the elements of collection, here array!
i am learning callbacks and i am unable to write the definition for each() function!! how would it look like??

each(collection,callback){
// code here
}

i would call it this way,
each(array,print);

Comment: @Aki G that looks right. Your `// code here` could be `for ( var key in collection ) callback( collection[key] );`

Comment: Thanks @Paulpro ! also i am confused, how would be the definition for print(){
console.log(array[0]);
} 

how can this be used as callback to the each function, when we are outputting just one element from print() function!

Comment: The definition of print would need to be like `function print (x) { console.log( x ); }`. Since `callback` will be a reference to the same function as `print`, `callback( collec[key] )` is just like calling `print( collec[key] )`.

Comment: So you'll be calling print inside your loop, once for each element.

Comment: Gotcha @Paulpro !!, ran it, runs as expected!! Thank you so much!