# JS arguments vs parameters

Tags: javascript, parameters, arguments

Different sources explain it in a different ways.
In the below example, which are arguments and which are parameters?

```
 const add = function(number1, number2){
       return number1 + number2
           }

    add(3,10)
```

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: as another user pointed out, this is a duplicate. [What is the difference between arguments and parameters in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12874467/what-is-the-difference-between-arguments-and-parameters-in-javascript)

---

Arguments are what's passed to a function at runtime. Parameters are what are defined in the function definition and alias the arguments.

> Parameters are variables listed as a part of the function definition.
>
> Arguments are values passed to the function when it is invoked.

Source: https://codeburst.io/parameters-arguments-in-javascript-eb1d8bd0ef04

```js
function moo(number1, number2) {} // parameters are defined

moo(10, 50, 100); // arguments are passed.
// notice that more than the specified number of parameters
// can be supplied and accessed via 'arguments'
```

Also see [arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments):

> arguments is an Array-like object accessible inside functions that contains the values of the arguments passed to that function.

Answer (score 1):

Parameters are variables listed as a part of the function definition. Arguments are values passed to the function when it is invoked.

```
const add = function(number1, number2){ //Arguments
   return number1 + number2 //Parameters
       }

add(3,10)
```